# What is the difference between install a package from source(tar.xz) & from rpm

Tags: centos

Take a look at [all openconnect versions](ftp://ftp.infradead.org/pub/ocserv/) & [this](https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=1229989).

---

For install from `source(tar.xz)` i act like this :

```
sudo yum remove ocserv
wget ftp://ftp.infradead.org/pub/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3.tar.xz
mkdir /usr/local/ocserv
tar xvf ocserv-0.12.3.tar.xz -C /usr/local/ocserv
cd /usr/local/ocserv/ocserv-0.12.3
sudo ./configure && make && make check
sudo make install
```

In this way `yum remove ocserv` tells `No Match for argument: ocserv`.
And in this way `sudo systemctl start ocserv` tells `Failed to start ocserv.service: Unit not found.`

---

For install from `rpm` i act like this :

```
wget https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/ocserv/0.12.3/1.el7/x86_64/ocserv-0.12.3-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
yum localinstall ocserv-0.12.3-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

---

What is the difference between install a package from `source(tar.xz)` & from `rpm`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source (tar.xz) is the source code for program, to install , you must compile and install with `make` and `make install`.

For the package `.rpm` the program is compiled and building, you must just install it with `yum`.

I hope it's helpful